# prototype Event Observer not working

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Please check what i am doing here false?

```
 Event.observe(form['postalcode'], 'blur', function(form) {return  updateCityname(form) }(form));
```

I am getting Javascript error "handle is undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this element an ID of "postalCode", it makes it a lot easier.

```
   $('postalCode').observe('blur', function(e) {
        var element = e.element()        
        var myForm = element.up('form')
        return updateCityname(myForm) 
    });
```

Comment: The context of an event handler is the element that triggered it. You can use `this` instead of `e.element()`